# Reading from a file containing unmappable characters

Tags: java, file-io

I am attempting to use File and Scanner to read through a .txt file and grab the useful information within into a separate file. Some of these files contain Chinese characters and its causing my Scanner to throw the following error "java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException:". The Chinese characters are of no importance, so how do I make the scanner ignore the Chinese characters and keep searching the rest of the file for useful information?

Here is the code:

```
            try {
                File source = new File(this.parentDirectory + File.separator + this.fileName.getText());
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(source);
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    str.append(reader.nextLine());
                    str.append("\n");
                }
                if (reader.ioException() != null) {
                    throw reader.ioException();
                }
                reader.close();
                this.input.setText(str.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File not found!");
                return;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scanner implicitly converts between an external sequence of bytes, and the 16-bit Unicode characters used by all Java Strings.

You need to know the actual encoding used for the external data (i.e., the file content). Then you declare your Scanner as

```
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(file, charset);
```

Having done that correctly, then there should be no 'unmappable' characters.

If you don't specify the charset explicitly, then the platform default is used, which is probably UTF-8.

Alternatively, it seems that you're not really using the Scanner to any significant degree; you're just using it to collect lines.   You could drop down a level and use a FileInputStream to read the file as a sequence of bytes, and use whatever heuristics you think appropriate to determine the 'useful' parts of the file.